# How to put custom object in Bundle?

Tags: android

I tried to put custom object into bundle using `putSerializable()` and `putParcelable()` but both are giving same error "cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable" and "cannot be cast to java.io.Parcelable".

I don't understand why this problem appears?

My code:

```
FragmentA objA=new FragmentA();

  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putSerializable("objB", (Serializable) objA);


    }
```

Logcat status:

```
FragmentA cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to have the object implement Serializable or Parcelable.  But you can't do that for fragments, so you need to find another way (such as recreating a copy of the fragment in the new activity).